# Query here is running for more than 120 Seconds

Tags: apex, soql

I have a method doing a simple query where in this case it will only ever have one `IZTripID` in the Set, I am getting an error(warning?)

> Query here is running for more than 120 Seconds sfdc

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Or am I missing something when thinking about the context that this is running, the `Map<ID, Trip__c>` is being used after this to make a service callout.  To add, is this error an aggregate of all queries running in the context or is it just for that specific one?

```
public static Map<ID, Trip__c> getTripFromIZTripIds(Set<String> iZTripIds)
{
    Map<ID, Trip__c> result = new Map<ID, Trip__c>();

    try
    {
        result = new Map<ID, Trip__c>([SELECT HotelResponse__c, RateMemberCouldHaveBookedWithHotel__c, IZTripID__c, HotelConfirmationNumber__c FROM Trip__c WHERE IZTripID__c = : iZTripIds]);
    }
    catch(QueryException error)
    {
        Exception.recordError('TripHandlerServices', 'getTripFromIZTripIds', error);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I believe if your filter `Set` contains `null` it causes a table scan. You might try just calling `iZTripIds.remove(null)` before running the query.

Answer (score 2):

1. Shouldn't you use `IN` instead of `=`?

`WHERE IZTripID__c IN :iZTripIds`

2. How many `Trip__c` records have you got in total in your DB? You might want to consider adding additional INDEXED fields in the WHERE clause to make sure you're not touching the whole table.

Comment: TBH I don't know the difference between IN: and =:, I thought the `:`tells the query that it is an iterable value, and I have about 100k Trip records where many of these `IZTripID__c ` may be null.  So if I add `Where IZTripID__c != null AND  IZTripID__c =: iZTripIds` it may speed it up?

Comment: You've got all the answers here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Comment: @EricSSH `IN` and `=` can both be used on sets and lists (I prefer `=` because it's shorter). `!= NULL` causes a full-table scan at best. Odds are, you need to add External ID to IZTripID__c to cause it to be indexed.

Comment: @EricSSH,1.In the code, make sure to run the query unless iZTripIds!=null. 2.I would suggest running this query in the dev console hard coding the iZTripIds in the where clause and check the cost of it. If the cost is high, try marking the custom field 'unique' or 'externalId' if possible. If this is not possible for some reason(formula fields, etc.,.), suggest getting the custom field indexed by SF support. SF support have a quick turnaround time indexing fields in my experience:)